# Android: using mediaplayer inside recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer

I want to use mediaplayer in each item of my recycler view. I want to play audio immediately on a particular item when its shown.

I am trying:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
vhplaymusic = (PersonViewHolderplaymusic) viewHolder;
mp = MediaPlayer.create(viewHolder.itemView.getContext(), Uri.parse(context.getExternalFilesDir("krishna").getPath() + "/amalharinaam_finalcut_loud.mp3"));
mp.start();
}
```

when in try to run, It says mp is null.

logcat for the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.simha.sacredindaapp, PID: 29281
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.simha.yatras.Myplanshowrvadapter.onBindViewHolder(Myplanshowrvadapter.java:410)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5217)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5250)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4487)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4363)
```

Comment: use `Uri.fromFile(File file)`, not `Uri.parse`

Comment: uri.parse gives the correct path of the file. I dont think thats causing problem.

Comment: it says mp is null

Comment: what does the logcat look like?

Comment: do you have any `"create failed:"` in the logcat?

Comment: No. Nothing like that.

Comment: tried `Uri.fromFile`?

Comment: I found why its showing null. Because the file does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a new MediaPlayer, you should do it in the following way:

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mPlayer.setDataSource(context.getExternalFilesDir("krishna").getPath() + "/amalharinaam_finalcut_loud.mp3"));
mPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Using prepareAsync() you won't block the application while the audio is being loaded, so we need a callback method to reproduce the audio once it's loaded:

```
mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {
                            Common.dismissLoading(progressDialog);
                            if (mPlayer != null) {
                                mPlayer.start();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

After that, you can handle pauses and resumes with `mPlayer.start();` and `mPlayer.pause();` ; and finally, when you don't want the audio anymore `mPlayer.release();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the media player in `recyclerview` by doing:

```
       MediaPlayer animalTrack = 
       MediaPlayer.create(holder.itemView.getContext(),R.raw.r1);
                animalTrack.start();
                animalTrack.setLooping(true);
```